# How can I identify whether a browser/reader is being used by someone who is visually impaired?

Tags: browser, accessibility, wcag

I have to provide a 508-compliant version of a page for the visually impaired and it isn't practical to just modify the page.  Thus, I have created a new "reader-compatible" version of the page for the handicapped.  The question is how I can tell if someone is using a reader rather than a standard browser?  Is there a "header" or "useragent" value typically used by these non-standard browsers that I can look for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it be possible to simply have an entrance page that gives the user a choice, or does it have to be automatic?

Comment: Not that I know of... anyway while doing some Googling I came upon this, although it does not solve your problem I guess it may be helpful: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/

Comment: Thanks guys.  I *may* have to settle for a separate link for the handicapped but I'd rather not.  Nico - thanks for the link; I am very familiar with it though as I've had to work through it as I update the site to meet the 508 compliance requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After corresponding with a number of people who specialize in accessibility or who actually build readers for the accessibility market, the conclusion is that there is no way to tell if a visitor is using a reader.  Thus, the only alternative is to ask the user before they are routed to a page that has different versions for a reader/non-reader.

Comment: That's it. Assistive technology usually rely on MSAA2 (or the OS X and Linux equivalent) to provide access not only to the browser but before that to the OS. Maybe there a few tricks to detect the use of MSAA2 but it'd be highly unreliable I believe.

Comment: It should also be noted that this "separate but equal" approach should be used only as a last resort - which might be justified in your specific case, but I want to call this out for any casual readers who stumble on this answer without that context. Accessibility is not a binary option; there are many users with varying degrees of sight, and sighted users who require keyboard access, who would not be at all happy at having to forego whatever design features are on the main page.